# What determines the number and types of values a continuation can be applied to?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, continuations

*The Scheme Programming Language* says

> Scheme allows the continuation of any expression to be captured with
>   the procedure `call/cc`. `call/cc` must be passed a procedure `p` of
>   one argument. `call/cc` constructs a concrete representation of the
>   current continuation and passes it to `p`. The continuation itself is
>   represented by a procedure `k`. Each time `k` is applied to a value,
>   it returns the value to the continuation of the `call/cc` application.
>   This value becomes, in essence, the value of the application of
>   `call/cc`. **If `p` returns without invoking `k`, the value returned by
>   the procedure becomes the value of the application of `call/cc`.**
>
> The continuation itself is represented by a procedure. Each time this procedure is applied to **zero or more values**, it
>   returns the values to the continuation of the `call/cc` application. That is, when the continuation procedure
>   is called, it returns its arguments as the values of the application of `call/cc`.

Consider `call/cc(p)` with `p(k)`.

Since "`k` as a procedure can be applied to zero or more values", what determines the number and types of values continuation `k` can be applied to?

Since the values of an application of `call/cc` depends on whether `p`  returns with or without invoking `k`, must the following   agree with each other:

- the number and types of values which  `k` can be applied to, and
- the number and types of values which `p` returns?

Comment: No them do not need to agree with each other: `(let ((l (call-with-values (thunk (call/cc identity)) list))) (case (length l) ((1) ((first l) 24 (first l))) ((2) ((second l) (first l) (first l) (first l))) ((3) 42)))`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. Could you write a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the question.  But consider a form like this

```
(call/cc p)
```

`p` must be a function *of a single argument*, and that argument will be bound to the procedure representing the continuation.  We can make that explicit by replacing `p` with an explicit `lambda` form:

```
(call/cc (λ (k)
           ...))
```

Now, `k` is itself a procedure, and when called

> will abandon whatever continuation is in effect at that later time and will instead use the continuation that was in effect when the escape procedure was created. [...] The escape procedure accepts the same number of arguments as the continuation to the original call to [`call/cc`].

(From [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)).

(Warning, lie ahead: read further where I will point it out.)

That quote makes sense if you've spent enough time thinking about programming languages in terms of continuations.  If you haven't, or if like me you have to work it out every time you see it then the critical insight is that *invoking a continuation is returning*: languages specified in terms of continuations, as Scheme is, have functions which, instead of returning, simply invoke the continuation representing 'the rest of the program after the function returns' passing it the value they want to return.

So, then, you can think think about invoking `k` as *returning, immediately, from the call to `call/cc` which created `k`*, because that's what '[using] the continuation that was in effect when the escape procedure was created' means.

So, well, we need, somehow, to give `k` some information which tells it *what value to return*, and that information is its argument.  So, for instance:

```
(call/cc (λ (k)
           (k 1)))
```

will return `1` (will invoke the continuation in place when `call/cc` is called with the value `1` to use the proper language).

And the 'abandoning whatever continuation is in effect' language means that it returns *immediately*.  So for instance

```
(call/cc (λ (k)
           (k 1)
           (display "not reached")))
```

Does not display `not reached`, and

```
(define (maybe-explode-the-bombs check?)
  (if (check? 'really-explode?)
      (explode-the-bombs)
      (dont-explode-the-bombs)))

(call/cc maybe-explode-the-bombs)
```

Neither explodes nor does not explode the bombs, but instead returns `really-explode?`.

So, well, here's the lie I told: I assumed that continuations take one argument, or equivalently functions return a single value.  That's true in many languages, but it's not true in Scheme (or Common Lisp): some continuations can accept zero, or more than one argument, or equivalently some functions can return zero, or more than one values.

Where this can happen in Scheme is pretty restricted: a continuation needs to get exactly the number of arguments it expects, and there's only one way of making a continuation which expects other than a single argument (it's possible I am wrong about this: I'm not a Scheme standards person).  The way of creating a continuation which expects other than one argument (*aka* allowing a function to return other than one value) is `call-with-values` and the way of returning other than one value (invoking your continuation with other than one argument ...) is `values`.  So

```
(call-with-values f1 f2)
```

calls `f1` with no arguments, with a continuation which accepts the same number of arguments that `f2` does.  When that continuation is invoked, `f2` is called with its arguments.  So

```
(call-with-values
 (λ () 1)
 (λ (a) a))
```

is an elaborate way of returning `1`, while

```
(call-with-values
 (λ ()
   (values 1 2))
 (λ (a1 a2)
   (cons a1 a2)))
```

Returns `(1 . 2)`.

And you can construct continuations which are unfussy about the number of arguments they get:

```
(call-with-values
 (λ ()
   (values 1 2 3))
 (λ a a))
```

for instance.  I suspect most implementations have something like this in their top-level REPL so they can print all the values things return without being fussy.

How does this relate to `call/cc`?  Well: the lie I told was that the procedure representing the current continuation, `k` above, returned a single value & hence expected a single argument.  That's not true: `k` can be called with any number of arguments and it passes all of its arguments to the continuation in place when the `call/cc` which created it was called.  In other words, `k` immediately returns all of its arguments as values from the `call/cc` which invoked it.  So:

```
(define (silly f)
  (f 1 2))

(call-with-values
 (λ ()
   (call/cc silly)
   1)
 (λ (a b)
   (cons a b)))
```

Returns `(1 . 2)` even though it looks like it should be an error, because the place in the first anonymous function where it wants to return a single value is never reached.

As I said above, REPLs typically have some facility for being unfussy about values, so you can experiment with this interactively:

```
> (call/cc (λ (k)
             (k 1 2 3)))
1
2
3
```

So, to answer the two specific questions you had:  If you have some function `p` with one argument, and then you say `(call/cc p)`, then there are two ways in which this form can return (can invoke its continuation):

- `p` can return normally, returning some number of values, which will then be returned from the `call/cc` form;
- the argument `p` got is a procedure, and if it calls it then it it will immediately return from the `call/cc` form, returning its arguments as values.

Scheme is dynamically typed, so whether the types of the things that get returned are valid or not is up to the program, at runtime.  Usually the *number* of return values needs to be the same between the two mechanisms because, usually, continuations expect a fixed number of arguments.  But this does not have to be the case: as I showed above you can construct continuations which are as fussy or unfussy about the number of arguments they expect as you like.

---

Finally, for added value, you can write `values` in terms of `call/cc`!

```
(define (values . vals)
  (call/cc (λ (k)
             (apply k vals))))
```

(Obviously it would be insane to do that, but you can do it.)

---

And really finally, all answers which talk about `call/cc` should include this:

```
((λ (c)
   (c c))
 (call/cc (λ (c)
            (c c))))
```

If you understand what this does, you understand the full horror of `call/cc`.  Do not run this code if your machine is liable to tentacles.

Comment: IMHO, last piece of code better looking as `((λ (c) (c c)) (call/cc call/cc))`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: yes, now I have to work out how that works again!